# Get CloudFront custom domain in the headers of a request

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I have a CloudFront distribution `abcd1234.cloudfront.net` and I've added a custom domain of `mysite.com` to the distribution.

- **The CloudFront distribution's origin:** `aaabbbccc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
- When I load the page `mysite.com/hello/world`, CloudFront is then consuming API Gateway `aaabbbccc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/{proxy+}`
- the API Gateway path endpoint is invoking a Lambda Function that calls a function like `getPageContent(customDomainName, pagePath)` which should be `mysite.com` and `/hello/world` respectively.
- However, inside that function, the `Host` header that eventually makes it into the function's `event.headers.Host` value is never the custom domain. Instead, the `Host` header is always `aaabbbccc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

**I want `headers.Host` to equal `mysite.com` (or another header to show that the request comes from `mysite.com`, but no matter what I do, the Host value is always just the origin url.**

Edit: I tried whitelisting `Host` and it caused the site to break completely, with the error about not being able to reach the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: To clarify: you configured your own CloudFront distribution and one of the custom origins is the `xxxx.execute-api.xxxx` endpoint hostname of an API Gateway API?  You're not referring to the hidden CloudFront distribution that API Gateway creates and controls... is that right?

Comment: Yes, the origin of the distribution is the endpoint hostname of the api-gateway API. When I actually inspect the "Host" header in my lambda functions via loggings to CloudWatch, I see that headers.Host is the value of the CloudFront distribution ugly-url, not the custom domain.

Comment: That doesn't really add up.  The original hostname should necessarily be lost (discarded) in order for the request to be correctly routed to the API Gateway endpoint -- and you seem to have proven that it breaks, as expected, if you forward (preserve) the original Host header.  Unless CloudFront is somehow reconstructing it from headers exchanged during its internal interactions (hmmm...), it should be impossible-by-design to find anything related to the original request hostname in this configuration.  I'll try to duplicate.

Comment: If it is helpful, I can provide more details, like the CF configuration json, etc

Comment: It may be a little while before I have an opportunity to try, but I'll see if I can duplicate this with Lambda.  With an HTTP integration, both with and without "proxy" enabled, I can't:  I get the expected result, the host header (which I map over to X-Forwarded-Host in the integration request) is set to the execute-api hostname. (I have a CloudFront distribution with an API Gateway API as the origin server, like you.) There are some members of the API Gateway team that read SO, so one of them may come along and be able to clarify how this is even possible and what the workaround might be.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot can you explain how you actually pass the value to x-forwarded-host? Do you hard code it?

Comment: If you've been through several iterations with this, you might go back and double check that you haven't at some point configured this value statically in your method or integration request.  That's the only explanation I have at the moment.

Comment: I was unable to figure out how to map one header to another (i.e. Host -> x-forwarded-host), as you are alluding to. I had looked around for examples of this but I only see people talking about it but never explaining it

Comment: Enter `Host` under "name" under HTTP Request Headers in the Method Request, then in the Integration Request, HTTP Headers, Name = `X-Forwarded-Host`, Mapped from = `method.request.header.Host`.  Since what I was using is an HTTP integration, the Host header sent to the backend is, of course, the actual hostname of the backend, which is why I had to remap it.  This doesn't preserve the original Host header sent to CloudFront, just the execute-api hostname sent to API Gateway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147581/discussion-between-kristian-and-michael-sqlbot).

Comment: I'm afraid there may have been a miscommunication originally. i've revised my question to clarify as much as i can. @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: That makes much more sense. :)  I don't believe there is a native solution for this until [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-lambda-at-edge.html)  becomes available.  By the time the request arrives at API Gateway, the original host header is lost, but a Lambda@Edge viewer request trigger should be able to fire before that, and clone the original header to a new header, to pass through.  I have not heard anything about when it might be out of preview and generally available.