# Forward Host header from CloudFront to API Gateway proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I've setup my CloudFront distribution to use a wildcard CNAME (*.domain.com)
I'd like to know the subdomain in my Lambda Proxy Integration. For this i need the Host header which is available in CloudFront Access Logs under x-host-header.

API Gateway assigns Host header to example.execute-api.https://forums.aws.amazon.com/.amazonaws.com endpoint name.

Is it still not possible to realise this with API Gateway? Adding an additional lambda origin request adds too much overhead and cost.

Additional resource related to this:
Link: [Get CloudFront custom domain in the headers of a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741358/get-cloudfront-custom-domain-in-the-headers-of-a-request)
Link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84588&start=75&tstart=0

Comment: Perhaps, if you whitelist the `Host` header in CloudFront distribution's *Cache Behavior* settings then this might make the `Host` header to be forwarded to the origin and show in the logs.